# testing React Highcharts config object with formatter callback

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, highcharts, jestjs

I'm running into an issue using Jest to test a helper function that generates my config object needed by the `<ReactHighcharts />` component. For configs that use the `formatter` callback, my expected object is visually identical to my received object, but the test still fails. I'm definitely sure that the `formatter` callback is what's causing the test to fail -- commenting that out gets the test to pass. How can I actually test this config?

Answer (score 1):

`formatter` is a function, and so needs to be mocked out in the expected test object to achieve object equality. In Jest, you can use something like `formatter: expect.any(Function),`.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [react-test-renderer](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-renderer.html) to test the formatter function.

App.spec.js

```
import TestRenderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import App from './App';

describe('<App>', () => {
  it('should render component', () => {
    const app = TestRenderer.create(<App />);
    const formatter = app.getInstance().state.hcOptions.tooltip.formatter;
    const obj1 = {
      x: "Jan",
      y: 10,
      f: formatter
    };

    const obj2 = {
      x: "Jan",
      y: 60,
      f: formatter
    };

    expect(obj1.f()).toBe(" Data not available ");
    expect(obj2.f()).toBe("<b>Jan</b><br/> 60");
  });

});
```

App.js

```
this.setState({
  hcOptions: {
    chart: {
      zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Average Monthly Precipitation and Temperature in Karasjok, 2021',
      align: 'left'
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: 'Source: ' +
        '<a href="https://www.yr.no/nb/historikk/graf/5-97251/Norge/Troms%20og%20Finnmark/Karasjok/Karasjok?q=2021"' +
        'target="_blank">YR</a>'
    },
    xAxis: [{
      categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
        'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
      crosshair: true
    }],
    yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
      labels: {
        format: '{value}°C',
        style: {
          color: "rgba(0,0,0,0)"
        }
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Temperature',
        style: {
          color: "rgba(0,0,0,0)"
        }
      }
    }, { // Secondary yAxis
      title: {
        text: 'Precipitation',
        style: {
          color: "rgba(0,0,0,0)"
        }
      },
      labels: {
        format: '{value} mm',
        style: {
          color: "rgba(0,0,0,0)"
        }
      },
      opposite: true
    }],
    tooltip: {
      shared: true,
      formatter () { 
      
        if(this.y < 50){
          return  ` Data not available `;
        }else{
          return  `<b>${this.x}</b><br/> ${this.y}`;
        }
      }
      
    },
    legend: {
      align: 'left',
      x: 80,
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      y: 80,
      floating: true,
      backgroundColor:
        Highcharts.defaultOptions.legend.backgroundColor || // theme
        'rgba(255,255,255,0.25)'
    },
    series: {
      name: 'Precipitation',
      type: 'column',
      yAxis: 1,
      data: [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100],
      tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' mm'
      }

    }
  }
})
```